# configuration.yml has an error: * Unrecognized field at: driverClass - DROPWIZARD

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm getting the following error when launching a Dropwizard application that uses a database connection to MySQL:

```
configuration.yml has an error:
* Unrecognized field at: driverClass
Did you mean?:
  - database
  - server
  - metrics
  - logging
```

Configuration.yml:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http 
    port: 9010
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
    port: 9011
  database:
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    user: ppub_web
    password: password
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:to connect port
```

Configuration class:

```
public class ConfigurationClass extends Configuration{

@Valid
@NotNull    
@JsonProperty("database")
private DataSourceFactory datasourceFactory = new DataSourceFactory();

public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return datasourceFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure that you class `DataSourceFactory` contains a field called `driverClass`
- Make sure you `Configuration.yml` is formatted properly according to the yaml specification . According to the error message, you have the problem exactly because of that.
- Make sure that fields in `DataSourceFactory` are accessible to Jackson (getters/setters or public fields or right Jackson annotations for allowing setting private fields)

P.S. You don't have to initialize `datasourceFactory` via `new DataSourceFactory();`

Comment: Thank you. I had the same error because of the incorrect yaml format.